# AngularJS second click in nested ngRepeat sends same data as first

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a nested object with calendar events which looks like this:

```
{
  'january': {
    1: {moment: 'Birthday', date: '1955/01/21'},
    2: {moment: 'Wedding', data: '1985/01/28'}
  },
  'march': {
    1: {moment: 'Birthday', date: '1955/03/21'},
    2: {moment: 'Wedding', data: '1985/03/28'}
  }
}
```

I want to show the items grouped by month:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="(month, items) in calendarItems">
  <div class="divider">
    {{::month}}
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="item" ng-click="openPopup(item)" ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.moment}}
  </a>
</div>
```

The problems starts when I click the first item. It sends the correct item data. If I click a second item it sends the same data as the first clicked item.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I just started with AngularJS and I have searched for hours, but I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Everything looks good in what you have up there, can you include the controller's code (implementation of openPopup)?

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code - and what you've shown here seems sound: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10722/ .

Comment: I don't know what I did, but now it works. Thanks for your help and time!